# How to fix Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color'

Tags: c#, .net, xna, xna-4.0

I have this code

```
string hex = "#FFFFFF";
Color _color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
```

I need to use _color in `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`

using previous code I receive this error:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Color' to 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color'

any idea how to solve this?
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you need?

```
public Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color XNAColor(System.Drawing.Color color)
{
    return new Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics.Color(color.R, color.G, color.B, color.A) 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved with this

```
  private Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color ConvertFromHex(string s)
    {
        if (s.Length != 7)
            return Color.Gray;

        int r = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(1, 2), 16);
        int g = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(3, 2), 16);
        int b = Convert.ToInt32(s.Substring(5, 2), 16);
        return new Color(r, g, b);
    }
```